# Unable to call function using infinite-scroll in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll

I am trying to implement a scrolling pagination, for this I tried many tutorials at the end found this [Tutorial](http://4dev.tech/2015/08/tutorial-implementing-infinite-scroll-with-angularjs-and-nginfinitescroll/). i wrote the code in a way it was instructed but not getting the desired output.

HTML :

```
<tbody infinite-scroll="getMoreData()">
    <tr ng-repeat="amenitydetail in amenitydetails">
        <td class="text-right">{{ currentOffset + $index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.name}}</td> 
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.address}}</td> 
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.phoneNumber}}</td> 
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.mobileNumber}}</td> 
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.city.name}}</td>
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.location.name}}</td> 
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.amenity.name}}</td>             
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.latitude}}</td> 
        <td>{{ amenitydetail.longitude}}</td> 
        <td class="">
            <a data-ui-sref="admin.masters_amenity_detail.edit({ amenity_detailId: amenitydetail.id })"
               class="btn btn-primary">                 
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </a>
            <a data-ui-sref="admin.masters_amenity_detail.delete({ amenity_detailId: amenitydetail.id})"
               class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My JS is as follows :

```
$scope.amenitydetails =     AmenityDetailService.findAmenityDetails(function (amenitydetails) {
            angular.forEach(amenitydetails, function (amenitydetail) {
                amenitydetail.amenity = AmenityService.get({
                    'id': amenitydetail.amenityId
                });
                amenitydetail.location = LocationService.get({
                    'id': amenitydetail.locationId
                });
                amenitydetail.city = CityService.get({
                    'id': amenitydetail.cityId
                });
            });
        });
        $scope.data = $scope.amenitydetails.slice(0, 5);
        $scope.getMoreData = function () {
            console.log("Coming to get more data?");
            $scope.data = $scope.amenitydetails.slice(0, $scope.data.length + 5);
        }
```

My log inside getMoreData function is not getting printed.Can anyone let me know where I am getting wrong??

Comment: Will you share your controller code and the html template?

Comment: @Dario The above JS code is my controller code only